# Multiple reverse ssh to provision Vagrant with Ansible

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

I have to provision a bunch of development vagrantboxes installed on different physical computers (OS X, Win, Ubuntu) with Ansible. As long as all ansible playbooks/roles/templates are unified (prod, dev) and stored in git, using ansible-pull and dealing with prod configs and vault that stores a real passwords is not an option. So the idea is to make every vagrantbox to create a reverse ssh tunnel to some server where ansible-playbook will be applied to a range of ports.
The question is: how to pick a free port from vagrantbox so I don't have to hardcode numbers to each VM created by developers?
Another question: is there any other, less complicated way to provision vagrant VMs working on different OS?

Comment: Have a look at the `vagrant-guest_ansible` plugin (https://github.com/vovimayhem/vagrant-guest_ansible). It allows to provision with ansible from hosts where ansible isn't installed or can't be installed (like windows). It automatically installs ansible within the guest and calls the playbook from within the guest.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but it is what I'm trying to avoid - copying playbooks and confidential data like passwords to guest machines or host machines.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that ssh automatically picks a free port if 0 is set as a port number. So running 
    ssh -N -f -R 0:localhost:22 user@middle-server
on my vagrant establishes a connection at the middle server where redirects localhost:port-picked to vagrant:22, and I can then apply ansible-playbook to a range of ports on middle server without copying playbooks to vagrant machines.